# CoreData Using Sqlite and Unicode Strings Fetch Not Working

Tags: sqlite, core-data, unicode, fetch

I have an application where i am storing japanese text in a coredata sqlite database. Populating the data seems to work ok (as far as I can tell), but when I search on any string field it returns no records.  If I search on one of my integer fields it does.

The string data is unicode (ie, Japanese characters), so my question is will core data not work with Unicode?  Seems unlikely.  Does something special have to be done so a search (fetch) will work?

Code to populate the data looks like this:

```
WordProgress *newWordProgress = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"WordProgress" inManagedObjectContext:progressContext];
newWordProgress.kanji = kanji;
newWordProgress.kanji = kana;
newWordProgress.senseIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:senseIndex];
newWordProgress.skillType = [NSNumber numberWithInt:skillType];

newWordProgress.leitnerDeck = leitnerDeck;
newWordProgress.dateLastShown = lastShownDate;
```

Code to test my fetch, looks like this:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kanji = %@", @"彼"];
NSFetchRequest *testRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[testRequest setPredicate:pred];
[testRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WordProgress" inManagedObjectContext:progressContext]];
NSArray *results = [progressContext executeFetchRequest:testRequest error:&error];
```

But returns no records, when I know that records were populated.

Just tried this too, and even this seems to fail.  I'm sure I must be doing something fundamentally wrong:

```
WordProgress *newWordProgress = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"WordProgress" inManagedObjectContext:progressContext];
newWordProgress.kanji = @"彼";
newWordProgress.kanji = kana;
newWordProgress.senseIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:senseIndex];
newWordProgress.skillType = [NSNumber numberWithInt:skillType];

newWordProgress.leitnerDeck = leitnerDeck;
newWordProgress.dateLastShown = lastShownDate;

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kanji = %@", @"彼"];
NSFetchRequest *testRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[testRequest setPredicate:pred];
[testRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WordProgress" inManagedObjectContext:progressContext]];
NSArray *results = [progressContext executeFetchRequest:testRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: It should handle Unicode, but that doesn't mean there aren't bugs in it. Could you post some sample code demonstrating the problem? (If StackOverflow can't handle the Unicode, maybe a screenshot).

Comment: Added code to my original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My god, I'm completely retarded, sorry.  Doing some more playing I saw the line...

```
            newWordProgress.kanji = kanji;
            newWordProgress.kanji = kana;
```

Doh!  It was completely overwriting my key field.  It should have read...

```
            newWordProgress.kanji = kanji;
            newWordProgress.kana = kana;
```

Thanks for the replies, guys.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Unicode problem, it's an `NSPredicate` error that would affect any string. You have:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kanji = '%@'", @"彼"];
```

The single quotes in there are the problem. You're creating a predicate that looks for a literal `%@` in the data. The single quotes prevent substituting the `@"彼"` for the `%@`. Take the single quotes out and it should work as expected:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kanji = %@", @"彼"];
```

Comment: I think I had it without '' before too, but I changed it to without and it still does not work.  I have also tried this with a template and it doesn't work either. :(